# DPI-проект "Hello World" на System Verilog в САПРе Vivado

Tags: c, dpi, verilog, system-verilog, vivado

Пытаюсь разобраться с dpi в system verilog. Пока что, [все что я нашел](http://project-veripage.com/dpi_tutorial_1.php), это то что *"все очень просто: импортируешь функцию в system verilog и используешь, как будто она была написана прямо на этом языке"*, но при этом в си-шном коде используются заголовочные файлы, которых точно нет в стандартном компиляторе.
Непонятно, где нужно писать сишный код так, чтобы САПР его увидел и вот всю вот эту кухню со стороны не написания кода, а подготовки рабочего пространства: что нужно дополнительно скачать, как настроить, что запустить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Симуляторы, поддерживающие dpi содержат заголовочный файл "`svdpi.h`", и разделяемую библиотеку(ки), содержащую реализации функций, описанный в этом файле.
Если программа на C -- простая, достаточно добавить в опции команды компиляции данный файл и симулятор сам скомпилирует этот файл.
Если программа сложная (например использует сторонние библиотеки), лучше скомпилировать ее вручную, указав комплиятору путь к заголовочному файлу, а линковщику путь к библиотеке и саму библиотеку.

В конечном итоге, после компиляции (самостоятельно или с помощью симулятора), в опции запуска симуляции, необходимо добавить ключ `-sv_lib` и указать скомпилированную библиотеку.